# MFC Worker Thread Not Cleaning Up On Unexpected Shutdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

x64 ... VS2015... Inside the function I call the thread as such:

```
 CString* arr = new CString("test");
 CWinThread *pThread;
 if(!(pThread->AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc, (LPVOID)arr))) {
 delete arr;
 }
```

For the Proc:

```
UINT ThreadProc(LPVOID pParam) {

CString* InputString = (CString*)pParam;



delete InputString;

return 0;

}
```

It cleans up fine if the thread finishes normally but if the application closes when the thread is running it leaves memory leaks. Under VS2008 debug didn't detect any leaks under VS2015 it does. Have there been changes to the way MFC cleans up threads since then?

Comment: It is quite normal that you get a memory leak when the thread gets killed before the string is deleted. You should get the memory leak even with VS2008. Anyway it would be cleaner to stop the thread properly before the program quits, that way the thread can do all necessary cleanup.

Comment: I was starting to assume that as well. I just recently upgraded to VS2015 after many years of procrastination. The debugger never registered any leaks under the same tests. Any way of checking for open threads in the destructor?

Comment: Not that I know, but you can easily do this yourself. Just wait on the `pThread->m_hThread` handle before leaving..

Comment: I already have a method of stopping a running process using a volatile bool flag. I suppose I could just check to see if the running flag is true and if so pop up a dialog if they are sure they want to quit and if on ID_OK terminate the thread from there. It's not an elegant solution but it doesn't quite differ much from the "Do you want to save your open docs" dialog, I suppose. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you stop your thread as you explain, you need to wait for the thread to finish by waiting on it's handle Once you've set the flag, the thread is still running, that's why you absolutely need to wait until the thread actually has finished.

Comment: If you leak memory during application shutdown, it's nothing to be too concerned about. Once the process terminates, all resources are reclaimed by the OS. A memory leak is an issue you need to address, when the process keeps running.

Comment: This seems to work for those who have similar problems:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proc:

```
UINT ThreadProc(LPVOID pParam) {
CMainFrame* pMainFrm = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
while(!pMainFrm->m_threadcancelflag ){
}

return 0;
}
```

In Header:

```
 HANDLE hThread; 
 BOOL m_shutdownflag;
 volatile BOOL m_threadcancelflag;
```

In Source:

```
CWinThread *pThread;

 if(!(pThread = AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc, (LPVOID)arr,    THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED))) {
delete arr;
}
else{

::DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), pThread->m_hThread, GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);


pThread->ResumeThread();
}
```

Override WM_CLOSE:

```
 void CMainFrame::OnClose() {
DWORD dwExitCode;

if(hThread){
::GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &dwExitCode);
if (dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE) {

if(!m_shutdownflag){
m_shutdownflag = TRUE;
if (AfxMessageBox(_T("Running Process. \n\nQuitting now may result in a loss of data and/or incomplete database tables.\n\nTo quit anyway click \"OK\"\nTo allow the process to complete normally click \"Cancel\"."), MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OKCANCEL) == IDCANCEL) {
m_shutdownflag = FALSE;
  return;
}
else {
m_shutdownflag = TRUE;
}
}


m_threadcancelflag = TRUE;
Sleep(500);
PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
 }
 else {
 ::CloseHandle(hThread);
 }

}

CFrameWndEx::OnClose();

}
```

Edit: Here is the complete solution... and for the record it is a bad programmer who doesn't foresee the unexpected and writes a program that does not clean up after itself and relies on the Operating System to do what the program should have done. Good programming habits involve adding error and exception handling as well as cleaning up after itself. Garbage collection is the basics in programming and even though it is easy to do when the program ends under ideal situations it involves a little more when it doesn't but good programming habits dictate that you must always foresee the unexpected. I hope this code helps someone else. This code will never leak memory due to ongoing thread regardless of how the program ends.